# Use position: absolute to set an image size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set an image size to its container size + 20px. The container size is relative and will change depending the screen size.

Usually, if I had to resize a div with a background, I'll just set it to position absolute with negatives positions values, but it seems like the img element doesn't follow the same rules. Any solution you know?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img />
</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.5%;
}
div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Try to add the property: display:block;
in the div img{}

Comment: That won't change anything because position absolute already changes the format context.

Comment: Why would the image need to be larger than the container? Its not logical.

Comment: I work on animations heavy applications, this is to achieve an environment effect. I'd just like to not recalculate the image size manually each time the screen/container size change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, absolute positioning removes the element from the flow of the document and thus it's container. If you want the image to be relative to the container that it is in, then the position needs to be relative, add the size to it that is needed.

Thinking about this logically, why not actually wrap an extra div around the primary content div and give it some padding?

```
<div id=container>
  <div id=content>
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Where container has the bg image and padding of 20px.

Comment: Ok, that'll work good enough for me. An extra element being bigger and the image just being 100% inside of it.

Comment: I just try to keep in mind when doing this kind of thing, don't try to make the markup/code fancy, just make it happen cleanly. The more we try to think up fancy ways of getting things done, the instances we have of seeing them break. K.I.S.S. is a hard one to remember sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use calc function.

```
width: calc(100% + 20px);
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7hbq5/14/

Calc function have a good support http://caniuse.com/#search=calc